# How to Move a DIV Back & Forth SLOWLY Overtop a Background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

Ok, so the full example I was going to show is no longer online so I will have to try to explain.

What I'm trying to do is have a looping video as the full-screen background, and overtop of that will be a DIV containing a video that continuously moves SLOWLY back and forth across the screen.

Here's an example of the animation portion, yet it's too fast:

[fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/vwH6R/2/)

HTML CODE

```
<div style='position:absolute; background-color: blue; height: 50px; width:50px;'></div>
```

JS CODE

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("div").stop(true,true).animate({left: 300}, 10000, 
          function(){ $(this).stop(true,true).animate({left: 0}, 1000); 
    });
}, 20000);
```

I'm not very good with javascript so maybe someone can just help me figure out the timing aspect.

Thank you!

Comment: Well with two videos on the screen at the same time, you DEFINITELY don't want to be using javascript for this.  You need to explore CSS Transforms.  Otherwise you'll kill performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument in the `animate` function is the duration of the animation, that determines how fast it will go. Right now it is 1000, which is 1000 milliseconds, or 1 second. Make that number bigger to make it move more slowly. However, the setInterval is going to kill you, it is going to stop it and call it again after 2 seconds, so that number needs to be changed to the total of both durations. However, that will be how long you will have to wait for the animation to begin. [See how that is working here.](http://jsfiddle.net/1dm3kpbj/) If you want the animation to continue forever in a loop, you can do it this way:
http://jsfiddle.net/bypepLf9/1/

Keep in mind you are doing two separate animations, one to the right and another to the left, and they can call each other when they complete because the final argument is a callback that will be called when the animation is done.

Here are the jQuery animate docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ but this should also be able to be accomplished through pure CSS.

Comment: Ahhhh...I figured that was how the time intervals worked, but couldn't understand why it didn't start immediately.  Your example should work perfectly.  Thank you for that!  And, yes, I realize the performance level won't be the greatest, but it's what the person wants.

Comment: Hey, Rusty...actually, I have a question.  When I take that javascript, put it in a script tag within the HTML head, it doesn't work.  I've tried this offline and loading the page through a web browser, yet the blue box just sits there.  Thoughts on what I'm overlooking here?

Comment: You need to put it at the end of the body and wrap it in ```$(function() {
// stuff here
});```
So that the jQuery won't try to run until the DOM is loaded. Your javascript is probably running before the `<div>` has been added to the DOM. You also need to make sure you actually have jQuery loaded on your page.

Comment: Haha, looks like you know just enough to be dangerous. It looks like your strength is more design, it looks cool. Is that NYC? $("vid") should be $("#vid"), and it needs to have `position: absolute` in it's CSS to be moved around like that.

Comment: Ha, I wish.  I'm self-taught on everything from music, design, and development...so it's a bit of a struggle at times when I don't quite understand the fundamentals.  I'd say I'm pretty good about taking things apart and putting them back together.  And, yes, that's NYC...I live in Brooklyn.  I can't think you enough for the help!  I really do appreciate it!

Comment: One more thing I overlooked, as I just realized this isn't going to act responsively.  How would you be able to edit the code in it's current state to adhere to the full-width of various sized screens?

Comment: Calculate the furthest left position by finding the width of the parent container and subtracting the width of the box:
`endingPos = $('div').parent().width() - $('div').width();
    $('div').stop(true,true).animate({left: endingPos}, 8000, moveLeft);`
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bypepLf9/2/)